# Javascript - auto-replacing a comma to a period (for input type="number") as you type in

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple JS code - the goal is to replace a comma with a period in 'real time' (ie. as user is typing in). For example, when user types in: 43,65 then it should be auto-corrected to: 43.65 etc:

```html
<input onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(',','.')" type="number">
```

But it doesn't work (at least in Firefox) - when I enter some number and add a comma, the number disappears completely. And when I type a period, it is removed. So it doesn't work at all as expected...

I also tried:

```html
<input onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, '.')" type="number">
```

but it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but only on `input` type `text`. `input` type `number` does not allow any other symbols than digits.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
function validate(){
  input.value = input.value.replace(/,/g, ".");
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="validate()" type="text" id='input'>
```

Comment: Number inputs allow floating point numbers. Shouldn't that mean digits, and periods, but not commas.

Comment: yes, I could do it via type="text" BUT then there is no 'arrow' near the input (I guess the point of html5 was to make life easier). Hart to believe why it  won't allow to replace a comma to a dot with a JS..

Comment: I will keep trying to make it possible.

Comment: @Kinduser tried what? Input number type allows periods, but not commas. So it automatically does what the OP wants.

Comment: If you were in Europe, we use commas as delimiters there, not a dot. but JS can only work / do calculations using a dot so that's why I wanted to auto-replace it..

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```js
function numbersOnly(event) {
  var key = event.keyCode;
  return ((key >= 96 && key <= 105) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || key == 188 || key==46 || key==8);
};
```

```html
<input onkeydown="return numbersOnly(event)" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(',','.')" type="text">
```

Comment: input type="number" allows floats when you add, eg. step="0.01" to it. Your code is nice - but it should probably also include backspace to be able to delete an entry if needed :

Comment: @Tom , backspace added

Comment: Maybe it will be useful to someone (if so, you may also want to make sure that the input accepts and leaves a period - for now it doesn't seem to..).

Answer (score 1):

To further explain what's going on here; if a user enters anything other than numbers or decimals into an input of type number `<input type="number">` the value will automagically be empty. This is why you cannot operate on input type numbers the way you want. If you want to achieve what you're setting out to do you will need to use an input type text `<input type="text">` and write a couple javascript functions to create the desired effect.

```js
function replace(element) {
  // set temp value
  var tmp = element.value;
  // replace everything that's not a number or comma or decimal
  tmp = tmp.replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, "");
  // replace commas with decimal
  tmp = tmp.replace(/,/, ".");
  // set element value to new value
  element.value = tmp;
}
```

```html
<input id='numberInput' onkeyup="replace(this)" type="text">
```

This code should get you started with an input box of type text which will exclude anything other than numbers and decimals, while converting any commas into decimals.

If you would like to keep a counter on the right portion of the input box you will want to add two buttons; incrementer and decrementer, as well as a function which converts the input value of the text input into a double & either increment or decrement the double depending on which button was pressed. If you have trouble with that part I would suggest posting another question.

Answer (score 0):

function to add commas to textboxes:

```
function Comma1(Num) {
    Num += '';
    Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');

    x = Num.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{4})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1))
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

i thinks this helps you